# error 400Bad Request auque la solicitud se realiza correctamente

Tags: php, postman

Hola como podria solucionar esto estoy aprendiendo a usar una API con PHP y postman prepare una consulta simple a una base de datos y aunque la peticion se ejecute y postman me muestre la consulta siempre me muestra un **400 bad request**

El codigo usado para la consulta es

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {

    if (isset($_GET['nombres'])) {
        $nombres = $_GET['nombres'];
        $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM estudiantes where nombres = ?");
        $sql->bind_param("s",$nombres);
        $sql->execute();
        $resultado = $sql->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        if (isset($resultado['nombres']) <= 0) {
            header("HTTP/1.1 204 No Content");
            echo "no hay registros";
        } else {
         header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
         echo "si hay registros";
    }
}
header("HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request");
```

Se supone deberia retornar un **204 No Content** junto con su aviso de que no hay registros, pero como mencione anteriormente aunque la consulta se ejecuta solo me muestra un 400 bad request

Comment: Y bien, ¿puedes explicarnos por qué tienes esto en tu código: `header("HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request");`? Ni siquiera aparece claro, analizando el programa, cuándo debería ocurrir una respuesta con código `400` y ese es el problema, no estás controlando adecuadamente el flujo de tu programa.

Comment: Para mostrar error 400 en caso que ningun metodo se ejecute

Answer (score 1):

Complementando la respuesta de A. Cedano, una refactorizacion del codigo podría quedar como la siguiente:

```
 if (strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) != 'GET') {      
    header("HTTP/1.1 405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED");
    die('Method not allowed');
}

if (! isset($_GET['nombres'])) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 422 UNPROCESSABLE ENTITY");
    die('nombres params is required');
}

$nombres = $_GET['nombres'];
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM estudiantes where nombres = ?");
$sql->bind_param("s",$nombres);
$sql->execute();
$header="200 OK";
$msg="Sí hay registros";
$resultado = $sql->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
if (isset($resultado['nombres']) <= 0) {
    $header="204 No Content";
    $msg="no hay registros";
}
header("HTTP/1.1 $header");
echo $msg;
die();
```

Pero en general, a tu código solo le falta detener la ejecución del proceso en los puntos correctos

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que escribas un código controlado, con una sola respuesta. Todo será más claro, más limpio y evitarás el error que estás teniendo ahora.

Considera que deberías controlar todas las posibilidades, decidiendo en cada caso cuál será la respuesta. Para tu caso, he supuesto que el código 400 se imitirá en dos casos: cuando la petición no sea del tipo GET o cuando en la superglobal GET no haya una clave `nombres`.

Veamos:

```
if (strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == 'GET') {      
    if (isset($_GET['nombres'])) {
        $nombres = $_GET['nombres'];
        $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM estudiantes where nombres = ?");
        $sql->bind_param("s",$nombres);
        $sql->execute();
        $resultado = $sql->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        if (isset($resultado['nombres']) <= 0) {
            $header="204 No Content";
            $msg="no hay registros";
        } else {
            $header="200 OK";
            $msg="Sí hay registros";
        }
    } else {
        $header="400 Bad Request";
        $msg="Revise el GET";
    }
} else {
    $header="400 Bad Request";
    $msg="Método no permitido";
}
header("HTTP/1.1 $header");
echo $msg;
exit();
```

Comment: Hola gracias por el consejo lo tengo mas o menos claro, aunque no se por que cuando el  $header devuelve un "204 No Content"; 
No me muestra el mensaje de 'no hay registros';

Comment: Bueno buscando mas al parecer cuando se devuelve header("HTTP/1.1 204 No Content"); 
Lo normal es no retornare ningun mensaje, entonces creo que voy bien gracias.

Comment: @FerDaniela en el contexto de una API tú puedes mandar un mensaje asociado a la respuesta, por ejemplo en un JSON y mostrar ese mensaje en el cliente.